# If statement isn't working properly with xml

Tags: android, xml

I've been stuck on this and I didn't find a similar case so, here is my question.

I'm trying to display an image based in the result of a Random method. If the Random's int is 3 (e.g.), the image displayed has to be the number 3.

The problem is that I can't match the result of the Random with it's proper image.

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView cIma01;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    cIma01 = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    generAle();

    String stri =  String.valueOf(generAle());
    Log.e(stri, "Number");

    if (generAle() == 0) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num0);
    } else if (generAle() == 1) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num1);
    } else if (generAle() == 2) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num2);
    } else if (generAle() == 3) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num3);
    } else if (generAle() == 4) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num4);
    }
}

private int generAle () {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(5);
}
```

LogCat says the result of the Random method was this (I tried 10 times in a row just for testing):

```
0, 1, 3, 4, 1, 3, 0, 4, 3, 1
```

But the images displayed were the next:

```
0, 4, X, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 3, 1
```

Not even close! The X is because in that case it didn't show any image at all (omg!)

I already tried some alternatives like to use switch case, but it's the same

Comment: if `generAle()` generates the random number then every time you call it, its just going to generate something different than what its previous value was. Call it once and hold onto the value

Comment: To understand the problem, I suggest you put a breakpoint in the line `Random rand = new Random()` and then debug your app. Check how many times is `generAle()` being called? Who is calling it? Why is it not working as expected?  You got the hints (and the answer right here if you need it), but try to solve it with the debugger. It will make you better :)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like I was calling generAle() too many times. I will also try to find my mistake with the debugger. I don't want to be stuck for days with this again. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `generAle ()` multiple times, on lines 8, 9, and in if-else statements.

Here's an alternative method:

```
public class Second extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView cIma01;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    cIma01 = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    String stri =  String.valueOf(generAle());
    Log.e(stri, "Number");

    if (stri.equals("0")) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num0);
    } else if (stri.equals("1")) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num1);
    } else if (stri.equals("2")) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num2);
    } else if (stri.equals("3")) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num3);
    } else if (stri.equals("4")) {
        cIma01.setImageResource(R.drawable.num4);
    }
}

private int generAle () {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(5);
}
```

You may also want to take a look at [the switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Comment: Why wrap the integer to a String for the if/switch case? Might as well use an Int.

Comment: It was a quick dirty rewrite, that's why I suggested it to be re-implemented as a switch-case statement. Thanks for the heads-up though.

Comment: Thank you Mustafa

Comment: @papejado Anytime!